# jQuery remove class on .click

Tags: jquery

Here is my html:

```
<a href="#">Read more</a>

<div class="moreDetails">
  <p class="additionalText">Some text help here, random length.</p>
  <p class="author">
    <span class="bolder"><a href="minidashboard.php?user_url=http://url.people/1332517">Name</a>
    </span>
  </p>
<div class="replies">
  <span>
    <a href="topic.php?id=http://url/topics/1049198">1</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Im then using jQuery to add a class to the `.additionalText` div when its text is longer than 36 chars.

jQuery:

```
$('.moreDetails p.additionalText').filter(function () {
  if ($(this).text().length > 32) {
    $(this).addClass('trim');
  }
});
```

What I now want is when `<a href="#">Read more</a>` is clicked the class `.trim` to be removed and reveal the content.

`.trim` sets the paragraph to a fixed height with overflow set to hidden.

Comment: Just FYI, I'm not saying your code doesn't work, but it is a little bit of an odd use of `.filter()`. You probably want to use `.each()` instead. Or with `.filter()` do something more like this: `$('.moreDetails p.additionalText').filter(function () { return $(this).text().length > 32; }).addClass('trim');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can give that link a class, like this:

```
<a class="readMore" href="#">Read more</a>
```

then add a click handler, like this:

```
$("a.readMore").click(function() {
  $(this).next().find('.additionalText').removeClass('trim');
});
```

This works by finding the `<div>` relative to the `<a>` via [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).  If the `<div>` doesn't *immediately* follow the `<a>` like in your posted code this may need some tweaks, for example if there are elements in-between but they're still siblings you'd need [`.nextAll('.moreDetails:first')`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) instead of [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).